# At/In the end of the parking lot

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> **At/In** the end of the parking lot, the car bounced over a curb and down a slope...

Is "at" or "in" correct here?

Comment: "at" because you are trying to specify a particular location where the event occurred.

Comment: **In the end** is generally used as a conclusion to an account of something, meaning **finally**: **In the end, they overcame their difficulties and lived happily together.** **In the end, the new development was scrapped because of opposition from local people.**